# iPad PDF reader that supports multi-page viewing?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, applications, pdf

Is there any app that allows the user to zoom out and see multiple pages of the same PDF simultaneously? (for example by zooming out the PDF).

Adobe Acrobat and other PDF desktop viewers have this feature but I haven't seen any App. for the iPad that includes it.

For example, on my PC I can get the following view of my PDF after zooming out by a factor of 12.5%:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That’s not a problem with GoodReader
>   for iPad – one of the only apps to
>   offer a special double-page mode for
>   viewing the entire spread!

[GoodReader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is one yet. All of them that I've had experience with (the built-in viewer, Zen Viewer, and PDF Expert) allow for full-page and 100% (or greater) zooming, but no multi-page.

Comment: Down voted because faB's answer below is indeed correct re GoodReader and this answer is not. I suggest this answer have the "best answer" undone and the questioner consider awarding it to faB's answer.

Comment: Agreed, GoodReader is a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wireshare is a FREE media viewer for iPad that nicely shows two-page spreads on PDF documents.  I also looked around a lot for this option.  I cannot comment on GoodReader because I have not used it.  But it works easily on Wireshare.

Answer (score 0):

SideBooks is a free app I just found that let's you read two pages side-by-side while in landscape mode among some other cool features. I'm actually very impressed with it since I found it for free.

Comment: Your answer would be more valuable with a link to the product you are recommending.